# AJAX Call gets 404 Error, despite the file being present

Tags: jquery-mobile, yql

I'm using jQuery Mobile on this [page](http://inventikasolutions.com/demo/tutsplus/site.php)

This is the link which I click -

http://inventikasolutions.com/demo/tutsplus/article.php?
siteName=nettuts&origLink=http%3A%2F%2Fnet.tutsplus.com%2F%3Fp%3D26607

There is a file article.php which can be visited by itself.

But when I click the link it doesn't work. Chrome shows a 404 error.

YQL also displays the result -
[link](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20feed%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2Fjamesaltucher%3Fformat%3Djson%22#h=select%20%2a%20from%20feed%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A//feeds.feedburner.com/nettuts%27%20AND%20guid%3D%22http%3A//net.tutsplus.com/%3Fp%3D26607%22)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that Apache server blocks un-encoded urls in parameters by default.

Here is the reason and solution for it:
[link](http://www.jampmark.com/web-scripting/5-solutions-to-url-encoded-slashes-problem-in-apache.html)